# Unable to write back changes to an access database after a table merge

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, merge, database-table

I have an access database containing a table called 'Items'. I have a number of smaller databases that also contain a table 'Items'. They each have a primary key called 'ID' and there are no duplicates.

The following code appears to merge successfully (if I put breakpoints before and after the merge dsi.Tables("Items").Rows.Count increases but the actual database is not changed.

Help!!

Thanks
Andy

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim dsicmd, dsacmd As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dsi, dsa, dsc As New DataSet
        Dim strSelect As String
        Dim strConnection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\TEMP\data\Account Data.mdb"
        Dim strC2 As String
        Dim cn, cn2 As OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommandBuilder        

        ' ** Items          
        cn = New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
        cn.Open()
        strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Items"
        dsicmd = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSelect, cn)
        dsicmd.Fill(dsi, "Items")        

        For Each f In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("d:\temp\data", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.mdb")
            If Not f.Contains("Account") Then
                strC2 = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & f
                cn2 = New OleDbConnection(strC2)
                cn2.Open()
                strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Items"
                dsacmd = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSelect, cn2)
                dsa.Clear()
                dsacmd.Fill(dsa, "Items")

                dsi.Merge(dsa, False, MissingSchemaAction.Add)                                

                dsa.Dispose()
                cn2.Close()
            End If
        Next

        cmd = New OleDbCommandBuilder(dsicmd)
        dsicmd.UpdateCommand = cmd.GetUpdateCommand
        dsicmd.InsertCommand = cmd.GetInsertCommand
        dsicmd.Update(dsi, "Items")

        cn.Close()
        dsi.Dispose()        
        dsc.Dispose()
        dsicmd.Dispose()
        dsacmd.Dispose()
        cn.Dispose()
        cn2.Dispose()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why did you use False in this statement: `dsi.Merge(dsa, False, MissingSchemaAction.Add) `

Comment: Hi Thanks. I used False as that was the in the example I found on MSDN. I have tried with True as well and it makes no difference.

Comment: I think you need to call `dsi.AcceptChanges()` instead of all these lines: `cmd = New OleDbCommandBuilder(dsicmd)
        dsicmd.UpdateCommand = cmd.GetUpdateCommand
        dsicmd.InsertCommand = cmd.GetInsertCommand
        dsicmd.Update(dsi, "Items")`

Comment: Hi. Have just tried. No luck. I looked at this. I think AcceptChanges is called as part of update and if you call it first then nothing gets updated - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/71a3d1e1-2588-499d-b603-c5c643f6fe50/datasetacceptchanges?forum=adodotnetdataset

Comment: You are right. However, I still believe the four lines I have mentioned before are not going to work. Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xzb1zw3x.aspx) how to write dataset changes to database

Comment: Hi. I have tried using SqlDataAdapter1.Update(Dataset1.Tables("Table1")) - in the above as dsicmd.Update(dsi.Tables("Items")) - and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updates are not getting written back to the main database because when you do the `.Merge` the new rows are added to the DataTable with their current `.RowStatus` in the other DataTable, which is `Unchanged`. So, when you call the `.Update` method the main DataTable has more rows than it did before, but they are all flagged as `Unchanged` so the OleDbDataAdapter assumes that it has nothing to do.

Instead, you need to `.Add` the new DataRows to the main DataTable so their status will be `Added` when the `.Update` takes place. The following code works for me. (It's C# code, but it shouldn't be too difficult to map it back to VB.NET.)

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace mergeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conExisting = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                conExisting.ConnectionString =
                        @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                        @"Data Source=C:\__tmp\data\existingStuff.mdb;";
                conExisting.Open();
                using (OleDbDataAdapter daExisting = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    daExisting.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                    daExisting.SelectCommand.Connection = conExisting;
                    daExisting.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Items";
                    var dtExisting = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    daExisting.Fill(dtExisting);
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("dtExisting has {0} rows", dtExisting.Rows.Count));
                    using (OleDbConnection conNew = new OleDbConnection())
                    {
                        conNew.ConnectionString =
                                @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                                @"Data Source=C:\__tmp\data\newStuff.mdb;";
                        conNew.Open();
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter daNew = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                        {
                            daNew.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                            daNew.SelectCommand.Connection = conNew;
                            daNew.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Items";
                            var dtNew = new System.Data.DataTable();
                            daNew.Fill(dtNew);
                            foreach (System.Data.DataRow drNew in dtNew.Rows)
                            {
                                System.Data.DataRow drExisting = dtExisting.NewRow();
                                drExisting.ItemArray = drNew.ItemArray;  // copy columns
                                dtExisting.Rows.Add(drExisting);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("dtExisting now has {0} rows:", dtExisting.Rows.Count));
                            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dtExisting.Rows)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ID={0}, RowState={1}", dr["ID"], dr.RowState));
                            }
                        }
                        conNew.Close();
                    }
                    OleDbCommandBuilder cbExisting = new OleDbCommandBuilder(daExisting);
                    cbExisting.QuotePrefix = "[";
                    cbExisting.QuoteSuffix = "]";
                    daExisting.Update(dtExisting);
                }
                conExisting.Close();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Using my test data, the console output is:

```
dtExisting has 3 rows
dtExisting now has 6 rows:
ID=existing1, RowState=Unchanged
ID=existing2, RowState=Unchanged
ID=existing3, RowState=Unchanged
ID=new1, RowState=Added
ID=new2, RowState=Added
ID=new3, RowState=Added

Done.
```

Comment: Thank you. I had figured the same thing eventually and used similar code that used ImportRow and then DataRow.SetAdded into a dummy table and then used GetChanges and Update.